# Order by last 3 months first, then alphabeticaly

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

I have been asked to order products on a site to show any products in the past 3 months first (starting with the most recent) and then the rest alphbeticaly. Currently the site is written in classes, and currently the products are ordered by date added. To minimise work load, I was wondering if the above can be done in one sql query? I think that It would need 2 seperate queries but I'm not an expert at sql so was wondering if this could be done?

regards

Phil

**EDIT**

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.name AS prod_name, pr.eye_size, pr.bridge_size, pr.opt_size, pr.price, pr.range_id, pr.date_added, ra.name AS range_name
FROM oa_product AS pr, oa_brand AS br, oa_range AS ra
WHERE pr.status = 'Launched'
AND pr.brand_id = br.id
AND br.filename = 'karenmillen'
AND pr.status = 'Launched'
AND pr.range_id = ra.id
AND br.status = 'Active'
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( 'm', GETDATE(
), date_added ) <3
THEN date_added
ELSE NULL , prod_name
LIMIT 0 , 6
```

getting error **MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' date_added ) <3 THEN date_added ELSE NULL , prod_name LIMIT 0 , 6' at line 11**

anyone know why?

Comment: I feel stupid. I added a comment after I read and missunderstood your question. I don't know if it's possible. But even if it is, would'nt the code be easier to read with two different queries?

Comment: It might also be faster with two separate queries, especially if you never need to show "the rest" (because it only starts on page 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MySQL syntax:

```
select * from Products order by DateColumn > curdate() - interval 3 month desc, ProductName;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using a CASE statement to treat all product dates older than 3 months as being equal.

Pseudo-code (in something approximating T-SQL)

```
SELECT ProductName, ProductDate
FROM   Products
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF ('m', GETDATE(), ProductDate) < 3 THEN ProductDate 
       ELSE NULL,
  ProductName
```

Comment: does it matter if the "ProductDate" is TIMESTAMP or DATESTAMP?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Assuming you're using SQL Server, then you cannot work out when a record was created using a TIMESTAMP - it doesn't encode the date or time - it's just an incrementing number. There is no such thing as a DATESTAMP datatype in any RDBMS I am aware of.

Comment: just checked in phpMyAdmin and type is DATETIME. I cant seem to get the above to work. I will put an edit in my question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two separate queries for that. You can make an expression that sorts the recent products first, then expressions to sort them differently:

```
...
order by
  case when ProductDate < adddate(month, -3, getdate()) then 1 else 2 end,
  case when ProductDate < adddate(month, -3, getdate()) then ProductDate else null end desc,
  case when ProductDate < adddate(month, -3, getdate()) then null else ProductName end
```

Comment: No need for the the cases on the second and third sort column.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, there is. Otherwise all records will be sorted by date.